# Anisotropic Poisson equation strong to weak form

Tags: calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

I'm trying to arrive at the weak form from the following strong form for the Anisotropic Poisson problem:

$$\begin{align*}-\nabla\cdot(\textbf{A}\nabla u) &= f \hspace{.5cm}\textrm{in }\Omega \\
u &= u_0 \hspace{.5cm}\textrm{on }\Gamma
\end{align*}$$

After multiplying by a test function and integrating over the domain, I'm not sure what to do with the tensor $\textbf{A}$:

$$\int_{\Omega}-v\nabla\cdot(\textbf{A}\nabla u)=\int_{\Omega}fv$$

When it's isotropic, such as $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, it acts simply as a constant; however, with anisotropy like $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$, it affects $\nabla u$ such that I don't believe Green's identity applies. So I don't think I can say

$$\int_{\Omega}-v\nabla\cdot(\textbf{A}\nabla u) = \int_{\Omega}\textbf{A}\nabla v\cdot\nabla u - \int_{\partial\Omega}u\textbf{A}\nabla v\cdot\textbf{n}$$

However, I don't know of any other identity which can help go from the strong form to a symmetric weak form. Any ideas?